# PHP: How do I run a loop during a certain time of the day?

Tags: php

I have a loop which runs in php..

I only want the loop to run if the local (sydney, australia) time is between 1pm and 3pm.

Can anyone provide an example of how this would function?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
if (date('H') == 13 || date('H') == 14)
```

above the loop.

(Given that your webserver is set to your local time.)

Comment: Can I also set it up in a cron to run between 1pm and 3pm?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Put in your crontab: `1 13 * * * some_user php /path/to/your/php_file`

Comment: just so I understand this correctly.. the loop runs continuously, and by setting up the cron with the above settings, it will stop the loop (ie: running the script) after 3pm, correct?

Comment: No. That just starts the loop at 1pm. If you want it to stop at 3pm put `if (date('H') != 13 && date('H') != 14) break;` inside your loop.

Answer (score 6):

you can use cron if you want to autorun some scripts at some time...

```
crontab -e
```

then add your script to be executed as following:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

Comment: Thanks Mishunika. I will be adding the cron as described below in comments, but thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (13 >= date('H') && date('H') <= 15)
{
 // your loop
}
```